# How can we securely enforce a rule that requires a new password to be 75% different from the previous one?

Tags: security, passwords

We have a customer that wants us to enforce a rule that when a user changes their password it is at least 75% different from the previous password.

Right now our passwords are stored with one-way hashes. We don't want to change that, because it would weaken our password security.

But if we can't get the original password, how can we determine whether the new one is 75% different?

Comment: Several websites force users to enter their old password as well as their new password on the same page.  You could capture the old password at this point and compare them.

Comment: Convince your customer that such rules often **decrease** security instead of doing any good. People cannot remember tons of strong passwords, so they will switch to weak passwords, - and they can get very inventive. Such rules also interfere with good password schemes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask for the old password when changing the password (you should probably be doing this anyways). Now you have the old password in server memory

Comment: That makes sense when the user changes their own password. Is there any way to do it when an admin changes it for them? The admin may not know the user's old password.

Comment: @JoshYeager You probably don't want admin knowing a user's password (for long). Have admin generate a long very random password, then send password reset email to customer

Comment: Thanks for giving me the obvious answer - I didn't think of that. I think we still might have more issues to work through, but your idea is a good start.